# How to merge lists of one document CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a document which has 2 list attributes

```
{
   CurrentDocument:[
      { DocName: "name1", DocType: "Identity" },
      { DocName: "name2", DocType: "Authorization" }
   ],
   ClosedDocument:[
      { DocName: "name3", DocType: "Passport" }
   ]
}
```

I want to have a query that return DocName & DocType of my two lists.
I can't use Join because if one of the list is empty, my query return nothing.
Furthermore, in case of a join, I can't merge all my attributes in one list.

```
SELECT cur.DocName AS curName, clo.DocName AS cloName FROM c JOIN cur IN c.CurrentDocument JOIN clo IN c.ClosedDocument
```

This query is not what I'm looking for cause :

- if one list is empty, I lost all data
- I get a list of value n*m which has duplicates (n : number of CurrentDocument, m : number of ClosedDocument)

I tried using the Union expression, but i can't seem to make it work in a query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UDF for this.
Create the following UDF

```
function userDefinedFunction(current, closed){
return current.concat(closed);}
```

Use it in your query

```
SELECT udf.MergeLists(o.CurrentDocument, o.ClosedDocument) as merged FROM Orders o WHERE o.id = 'a811d13f-a308-4df1-85c1-31e566e9fc1e'
```

This returns the following

[image]

Comment: Works fine, but the Request Charge is higher by 66%. (in my context 3 --> 5)
I will continue with my query selecting two attributes unfortunately :(
But thank you !